# ros-kinetic-navigation installation problem

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to install the ros navigation stack using apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation but it shows this error :

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-navigation : Depends: ros-kinetic-map-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried building from source and i still get error like this :

```
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'navigation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'map_server'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(map_server)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Bullet (missing: BULLET_DYNAMICS_LIBRARY
  BULLET_COLLISION_LIBRARY BULLET_MATH_LIBRARY BULLET_SOFTBODY_LIBRARY
  BULLET_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBullet.cmake:95 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  map_server/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mew/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mew/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:2068: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

is there any fix for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288210/ros-kinetic-navigation-installation-problem/) by [mewbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34476/mewbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It needs an old version of libpulse0
try running

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse0=1:8.0-0ubuntu3
```

---

Originally posted by [mewbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34476/mewbot/) with karma: 71 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mewbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34476/mewbot/) on 2018-04-10**:
it is working